# Spam prevention through IP tracking

Tags: web-development, ip-address, spam-prevention, moderation

I am building a website with user generated comments. In order to implement user moderation/spam-protection, users have the ability to mark comments as spam. When one comment is marked as spam, I want all comments from the same IP address to be deleted.

I am not familiar with spam prevention in general, other than Captcha.

Question:

- is this a feasible/good system for spam prevention?
- are there better ways, or improvements I can make?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this a feasible/good system for
>   spam prevention?

No, for a variety of reasons - chiefly:

**IP address assignments change over time.** Do you want to delete posts from 2011 in the year 2015 because a spammer was assigned an IP which had seen use prior?

**Malicious flagging happens.** Do you want a few malicious posts to interfere with comments from one of your community's top posters?

... etc.

> are there better ways, or improvements
>   I can make?

Spam is pandemic and hard to deal with... it's an [arms race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arms_race) and spammers have strong financial incentives to continue spamming.

Services like ReCAPTCHA and Akismet are dedicated to fighting this battle - they're good at it and they have an incentive to *stay* good at it.

Unless you want to spend time engineering and re-engineering your solution over time to fight spam, I doubt you want to fight this battle... but if you feel compelled to take on the spammers, here is how you might go about it:

**Require verified user accounts** - This means you will need to collect data from your users and verify that data (whether it be an e-mail address, payment information, or a phone number).

**Avoid automated destructive actions** - Don't delete anything until a moderator has had a chance to review the merit of user-reported spam. An example: vBulletin comment flagging and moderation.

**Slow spammers' roll.** Spammers prefer hit-and-run opportunities over creating accounts, but they *will* create accounts if it means immediate access to post at will. Consider implementing a "no links for accounts with less than 5 posts" rule to weed out spammers (they won't stick around to meet that limit unless they're particularly desperate) and a "+3 posts/day quota" for new user accounts (i.e. user can post 3 times on his or her first day, 6 times on the second, and so on).